# Unhandled exception when copying from a std::vector to a thrust::device_vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, thrust

I encountered the following error when trying to copy data from a `std::vector` to a `thrust::device_vector` using `thrust::copy`:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD7FF43E49 in tryThrustCopy.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: thrust::system::system_error at memory location 0x0000002CB3B9C8B0. occurred

I am using Windows 10 with Visual Studio 16, Visual C++ 2019 (version 14), CUDA 11.0, and my GPU driver version is 455.41.

The error is reported in the debug mode of the Visual Studio. The program in the release configuration runs from the command line, but would terminate at the copy step.

Here is my code to generate the error.

main.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "particle.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   

    std::vector<particle> particles(5);

    particles.at(0).x += 1; // Do something to the host vector.

    thrust::device_vector<particle> dParticles;

    dParticles.resize(particles.size());

    //Here comes the error.
    thrust::copy(particles.begin(), particles.end(), dParticles.begin());

    std::cout << "test 2 ends" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

particle.h:

```
#ifndef __particle_h__
#define __particle_h__

class particle
{
private:
    

public:
    particle() : x(0), y(0) {}
    int x;
    int y;

};

#endif
```

In general, I was trying to copy a host vector of particle objects to a device vector. I also found that copying integer vectors (`vector<int>`) from the host to the device using the above code works fine.

I really appreciate it if someone could point out where I made a mistake. I am new to CUDA, so any suggestions on how to check for the error is also welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I compile your code  on CUDA 10.2, I get the following warning (truncated):

```
.../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/allocator/allocator_traits.inl(97): warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed
```

*You should not ignore a warning like that any time you are doing CUDA or Thrust programming*

Unfortunately, for some reason I don't get that warning on CUDA 11.  Nevertheless it is an important clue as to the actual issue.

What function could it be possibly referring to?  It is referring to your constructor:

```
particle() : x(0), y(0) {}
```

*Evidently, that constructor is somehow being called in device code* (in the failing case)

Therefore the proper thing to do is to decorate that constructor with:

```
__host__ __device__
particle() : x(0), y(0) {}
```

This makes the warning go away (CUDA 10.2), and for me your code then runs without error on CUDA 11.

(On CUDA 10.2, the behavior is such that I get the warning, but even with the warning, the code runs without error.  On CUDA 11.0, I don't get the warning, but the code runs with the error unless you decorate the constructor properly.  So I assume there are significant differences in thrust behavior under the hood.)

However the general CUDA programming advice that I would give is:

> Any objects that you use in device code should have any possible methods that are callable in device code, decorated with `__host__` `__device__`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, this solves the problem. I didn't know that the constructor was called in the device. (Is it called when the device vector is being initialized?) Thank you for your advice.

Comment: On CUDA 11, I believe the constructor is being called on this line: `dParticles.resize(particles.size());`

Comment: Alternatively, could use `reserve` instead of `resize`?

Comment: reserve is a hint.  In retrospect, I think the constructor-on-resize makes sense.